# random equations in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
  function button(){
    text1 = 4
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
    var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
    var answer1 = rand1 + '+' + rand2;
    var html = rand2 + '+' + rand1
    document.write(html)
  }
  function check(rand1, rand2){
    var text11 = document.getElementById('id').value;
    var answer = rand1 + rand2;
    if(answer == text11) {
      document.write('correct!')
    }
  }
  
  button()
```

```html
<input type="text" id="id">
<button onclick="check()"> check </button>
```

I want my code to create simple equations. You can put in answers and it tells you if you are correct or not. When I run this simple code, input the right answer and click on check, it doesn't show correct. why is this and how can I fix?

Comment: Cause inside of your check function it can't reach the rand1 and ran2 variables. try to make them global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `check()` requires two arguments `rand1` and `rand2`, which you are not passing while calling it from `onclcik`.

Following code should work, check it...

```html
<html>
<body>

<script>
  function button(){
    text1 = 4
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
    var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
    var answer1 = rand1 + '+' + rand2;
    var html = rand2 + '+' + rand1
    document.write(html)
    return rand1 + rand2;
  }
  function check(){
    var text11 = document.getElementById('id').value;
    if(answer == text11) {
      document.write('correct!')
    }
  }
  var answer = button()
</script>
<input type="text" id="id">
<button onclick="check()"> check </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this shouldn't be the accepted answer, sry but the code is bad

Comment: I am kind of a beginner and I like more simple code @ChristopherAdels

Comment: you should learn with the better code and don't mislead other beginners finding this post, you can ask questions

Comment: @ChristopherAdels Yes, i know it's bad code, because to answer his/her question ("... why is this and how can I fix? ...") i needed to use same code as provided. So i just fixed provided code and pointed out logical errors.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot things not the "nice" way. It doesn't work because `rand1` and `rand2` are undefined. Declare them global or pass them with the function. Beside that, you shouldn't use document.write for this, replace a placeholder with innerText. And you should compare the values with `===`and not with `==`

Here is a example, but pls don't just copy/past it:

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<input type="number" id="result">
<button onclick="check()"> check </button>
```

```
const input = document.getElementById('result');
const placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
const randQuantifier = 4;

var random1 = getRandomNumber(), random2 = getRandomNumber();
placeholder.innerText = `${random1} + ${random2}`;

var answer = random1 + random2;

function getRandomNumber(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * randQuantifier);
}

function check(){
   if(answer === parseInt(input.value))
      placeholder.innerText = "Correct!";
   else
      placeholder.innerText = "False!";
}
```